# Python gethostbyaddr being slow

Tags: domain-name-system, socket

I'm facing an issue today I can't explain and I'm hoping someone will be able to put me in the right direction.

I have a fleet of EC2 servers running a python script. When a user connects to my servers (handled via a Load Balancer), one thing I do is getting their reverse name based on their IP address (or PTR).

Up until now, this is the code I was using:

```
import socket

details = socket.gethostbyaddr(request.user_ip)
print('User PTR is', details[0])
```

What I realized today was that querying `gethostbyaddr` could take a few seconds (it even took 300 seconds for some query!!). The average being at 1s, and a frequent number between 20 and 30 seconds !

(Some mentions `gethostbyaddr` having a timeout at 5s, which doesn't appear to be the case in my situation).

Now, reading about `gethostbyaddr`, it appears that it uses the `resolv.conf` (I'm using Debian 12) to find the reverse. In my servers, the content of that file is :

```
nameserver 172.31.0.2
search .
```

So my servers is relying on AWS's VPC DNS resolver.

What I did was track the time between the `gethostbyaddr` command and if it was longer than 1s, display the duration, along with the IP.

When I had some IPs, I ran the same code on the same server but on another Python shell, and often got a result in a few ms, or an error (unresolved host), in general quite quickly. A few had errors that could take seconds (or even minutes) to show up.

**My hypothesis** is that Python is queuing the `gethostbyaddr` command to run them sequentially, despite having multiple process, and if a few of them are stuck, the others will be delayed until some sockets are freed to be used for that query.

Does that makes sense ? Is this possible ?

So I tried an alternative: Instead, I built the reverse query using the arpa DNS ("[ip-in-reverse].in-addr.arpa.") and queried the DNS myself, directly, by using Cloudflare's DNS (1.1.1.1).

Doing so made the duration drop to a few ms, which cleared the issue.

I "kind of" fixed the bug, but can't explain exactly why it happened. I have quite a few servers connecting to my EC2 instance with an invalid reverse, so having the `gethostbyaddr` being stuck makes sense, but is it possible that other process using the same code could be stuck in some queue ? Maybe at the Linux level ?

Here are my hypothesis:

1. Debian (Linux) is queueing the queries to retrieve the gethostbyaddr and when a certain amount are taking too long, the others are put in a queue before being processed
2. Amazon has some troubles with their DNS or implemented some rate-limiting or delay for the queries, causing the resolving to be longer
3. ???

What am I missing that could explain the delays?

There is no need for code sample here, as the issue is not related to the code directly, but how `gethostbyaddr` is used.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How fast you get an answer depends on how fast the DNS server responsible for the domain will answer the lookup. The AWS DNS server will simply forward the query to the appropriate server (which might it forward to another one) unless the query and result is already cached. And since DNS is traditionally done with UDP such external servers might simply not respond at all in which case the requests will retried until some timeout occurs.

In general it is a bad idea to include a blocking DNS query (like gethostbyaddr) in your code, when the query needs to be externally resolved. You fully depend on some external server to continue in your program, but have no control how long the query will take.

Comment: That was the missing link in my head I think ; That `gethostbyaddr` is a blocking DNS query. This was causing the servers to be slow (awfully slow by moment). I identified the issue quickly and changed the query to a coded DNS query (using arpa DNS entries), which resolved the problem, but I wasn't sure what was the original issue.

"Blocking" was.

Thank you for your help!